# How do I save an ArcMap map document using VB.Net?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, vb.net

I am trying to save the map document that is currently open. How do I write the code? I have tried many suggestions that I found using Google searches, but nothing works. Currently I have:

Dim clickedDoc As IMapDocument = My.ArcMap.Application.Document
clickedDoc.Save(True, False)

which causes ArcMap to crash. I did get it to work with some other code, but it wouldn't actually save.

Also, this should be a background job. So no save dialog should come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the built in [ArcMap Command](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/858a508c-b771-467c-81e6-c6aa72d88f9c.htm) Save, see example below.

```
    Dim pUID As New UID
    Dim pCmdItem As ICommandItem
    ' Use the GUID of the Save command
    pUID.Value = "{119591DB-0255-11D2-8D20-080009EE4E51}"
    ' or you can use the ProgID
    ' pUID.Value = "esriArcMapUI.MxFileMenuItem"
    pUID.SubType = 3
    pCmdItem = My.ArcMap.Application.Document.CommandBars.Find(pUID)
    pCmdItem.Execute()
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked great. Do you know how I can change this to also make it save edits?

Comment: @Xoph, Please open a mew question regarding saving edits.